# Clockify Api - get hours for each user for the last 24 hours

Tags: postman, clockify

Hi I was wondering if you could help me.

What would be the right endpoint to get a report for hours logged for each user in a given workspace the past 24 hours? The API doesn't make it clear which report to use and what values to supply in a post request to get this result.

Excuse me if I seem a little naive about the capabilities, I have been asked to look at this without prior knowledge of the API and I'm just trying to get me head around it.

Answer (score 1):

Clockify just seem to have shut down their old api (I was using). The report API is documented here: https://clockify.me/developers-api#tag-Reports

And this works quite well. For your case, the requests could look like:

```sh
curl --request POST \
  --url https://reports.api.clockify.me/v1/workspaces/<YOUR WORKSPACE>/reports/summary \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --header 'x-api-key: <YOUR API KEY>' \
  --data '{
  "dateRangeStart": "2020-08-13T00:00:00.000Z",
  "dateRangeEnd": "2020-08-13T23:59:59.000Z",
    "summaryFilter": {"groups": ["USER"]},
    "exportType": "JSON"
}'
```

There is no "last 24h" though, you will have to adjust the dates yourself.

What might be interesting for your case:

- This example just returns all durations by user. If you want all time entries explicitely, add `TIMEENTRY` as summary group:

```
    "groups": ["USER", "TIMEENTRY"]
```

- You can also export it to a different format: `JSON`, `CSV`, `XLSX`, `PDF` are supported.

Comment: This was the report I ended up using, We used guzzel to get the request but thanks for your response.